# Login failed for specific user

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have created login account on my localhost\sql2008 R2 Server (user=test,password=test)
mapped to database 
my server ip is 192.168.3.2.
Authentication Mode on SQL Server is set to both (Windows and SQL)
When i login as server name = . and user = test,password = test or servername = 192.168.3.2 and windows Authentication mode, everything is ok.
But when i login as server name = 192.168.3.2 and user=test and password= test, it's not working  and shows me this error: Login failed for user 'test'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
any help on this please.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error logged in the SQL server log file and not the one displayed by the client, that will show the true error code, the one returned to the client is always a generic "state 1" error.

Comment: This post seems to be the same question, see if it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474839/unable-to-login-to-sql-server-sql-server-authentication-error-18456

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx