# Login failed for user '***' (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. I tried everything I could think of, but no matter what I get this error:

> Login failed for user
>   Server type : Database Engine
>   Server Name : .\SQLEXPRESS
>   Authentication : Windows Authentication

I've already tried Server names like `(local)`, `.`, `USERNAME\SQLEXPRESS`,  `USERNAME`, and `SQLEXPRESS`, but none of them worked :(

Details:

> Server Name: .\SQLEXPRESS
>   Error Number: 18456
>   Severity: 14
>   State: 1

My SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) is running as well as SQL Server Browser also.

Comment: Try logging into the computer as the local `Administrator` account, if you can. Local administrator usually gets `sa` in Sql Server Express. From there, you can grant rights to your normal account.

Comment: solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474839/unable-to-login-to-sql-server-sql-server-authentication-error-18456