# Unable To Open SQL Cnnnection With Windows Authentication - New SQL Server Install - Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1 Line Number: 65536

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssms

I recently received a new work laptop and had to have IT install SQL Server 2014 on it. Initially when they configured the machine I was not set as an admin on it, they made the change after they mailed it to me. When in SMSS I try to log in and get this error:

> Cannot connect to HENA009617-W541.
>
> Login failed for user 'My domain user name'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: HENA009617-W541
>   Error Number: 18456
>   Severity: 14
>   State: 1
>   Line Number: 65536

Does anyone have any recommendations on correcting this or would I have to have SQL Server reinstalled?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Windows authentication? If it's SQL Server authentication, is it enabled on the server?

Comment: Ensure the database is set for both SQL and Windows authentication.

Comment: I know when I have been able to log into SQL Management Studio I can click on the DB and check its properties but without being able to do that where could I check that?

Comment: I think I got it. I ran SSMS in admin mode and it let me log in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like your user wasn't added as a login on the local instance (what happens when someone with no knowledge of SQL Server installs it). If you're now logged in, I would add yourself as a login, and set your necessary permission. Running SSMS as Admin isn't really ideal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to login to SQL Server + SQL Server Authentication + Error: 18456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474839/unable-to-login-to-sql-server-sql-server-authentication-error-18456)