# Can't log-in with a SQL Server with SQL user [Server is configured for Integrated authentication only]

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have enable the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode but still get this error:

> Server Name: SQL-SERVER-AD
> Error Number: 18456
> Severity: 14 State: 1
> Line Number: 65536

When I look up the error logs I see it is due to [Server is configured for Integrated authentication only] but I enabled it.

Maybe is it because I have SQL Server Free version?

Comment: The client-side error messages are intentionally uninformative so as to avoid assisting unauthorized parties. If you have administration access to the SQL Server instance, check its ERRORLOG for the 18456 messages and compare the actual State number in there against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to login to SQL Server + SQL Server Authentication + Error: 18456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474839/unable-to-login-to-sql-server-sql-server-authentication-error-18456)

Comment: @AlexG it does not answer it. I already did that as I stated in my post. Still does not work u.u